# MPVolumeView with XCode 4 (Storyboards)

Tags: ios, xcode, slider, volume, mpvolumeview

How do you make a slider that adjusts the volume level of the device with storyboarding? I haven't found any information on this relevant to XCode 4. Is MPVolumeView still the way to go? If so, how do I implement it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use an MPVolumeView in Xcode 4.x and iOS5. Simply import the MediaPlayer framework (link to it in your project settings, too) and use something like this:

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,120,15)];
[someView addSubview:volumeView];
```

This will give you the slider that will change system volume when dragged.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a slider, you can add one to your view and link it to an action in the corresponding view controller. The action looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)volumeSliderChanged:(id)sender
{
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    float newVolume = slider.value;
    // Set new volume
}
```